# Spring + Hibernate how to prevent rollback

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a code block with this method:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class)
public synchronized Object saveData(){
    //...
    dao.insert(entity);
    //...
}
```

My dao class is marked ad Transactional

```
@Transactional
public class Dao {
   //...
   public <T> void insert(T obj) throws Exception {
    getSession().saveOrUpdate(obj);
   }
}
```

I need to prevent any rollback inside this block. However I got this:

```
2014-02-25 20:47:44 [WARN]SqlExceptionHelper:143    SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000
2014-02-25 20:47:44 [ERROR]SqlExceptionHelper:144   Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
2014-02-25 20:47:44 [ERROR]BigliettiService:?   Transazione in errore
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
...
2014-02-25 20:47:44 [ERROR]JsonHandlerExceptionResolver:?   Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

Why at the end I found a Transaction rolled back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Your transaction is being propagated by default to the inner method and if this method rollbacks your transaction, the outer method can only be notified by a  UnexpectedRollbackException that the rollback already happened.. and acknowledge it.

You can change the propagation config to start a new inner transaction but this won't help as it will still be commited independently before reaching the outer transaction.

If you can't set a NoRollback attribute at DAO level, I guess the best solution would be to remove the Transactional attributes from your DAOs and have a layer of facade services calling these DAOs and defining their own rollback strategies.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue just last week. In my case it was another `@Transactional` annotation from a different method that caused the transaction to be marked as rollback-only.

Did you check for that yet?

Edit: To clarify it a bit more, you didn't post your code from inside your `saveData()` method. What caused this error for me was calling another method with `@Transactional` (lacking the `noRollback` attribute) from inside my method, in your case `saveData()`.

Comment: I updated my question. I call a method inside a @Transactional class, but I hope this attribute is inherited, am I wrong? How prevent rollback without changing the Dao class (because many other inserts needs rollback)?  Thanks

Comment: I'm no expert for spring + hibernate and basically started using it myself only 2 or 3 weeks ago, so I can't give u a definite answer. But from what I've read when I had this problem myself the attribute is not inherited and that is what causes this error, because spring treats all surrounding transactions as rollback-only unless specified otherwise. I'm pretty sure that I fixed it by adding the attribute to my other method, but as you state that you can't just exclude the Exception.class from rollbacks in the DAO maybe just create a new class for that specific exception and ignore that.

Comment: Or maybe you could build a saveData() method (clone of insert) in the DAO just for saving the data and then annotate it with @Transactional(noRollbackFor=Exception.class). Then just call dao.saveData(entity); instead of calling insert()